# Can't locate Allow All cookies button with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Python and Selenium. I am trying to automate login process to a website but I can't pass the cookie wall because neither XPATH nor CLASS_NAME from HTML give me a correct location and click on the button, what am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://admin.pitcher.com/user/login")
print(driver.title)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.acceptAllButtonLower')

#allow_all_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'ALLOW ALL')]")
#allow_all_button.click()
while(True): pass
```

I have tried looking by CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH

Answer (score 1):

If you notice in the HTML DOM, you will see the presence of IFRAME within which the desired element is wrapped. So, you need to first switch into the IFRAME and then perform `click()` on Allow All cookies button.

Use below line of code to switch into the IFRAME:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@id,'pop-frame')]")))
```

**Below is the working code for your reference:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://admin.pitcher.com/user/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# below line of code waits until IFRAME is loaded and switches into it
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id,'pop-frame')]")))
# below 2 lines waits for Allow All cookie button to be clickable and clicks on it
AllowAllBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Allow All')]")))
AllowAllBtn.click()
# below line switches back from IFRAME to main content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```